# How to fix the scaling/positioning problem in helix3d models?

Tags: c#, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

Problem:

I am trying to create and render detailed building models with helixtoolkit.wpf.sharpdx. And some part of the model (mostly detailed furnishing and piping structures inside the house) is mis-scaled and mis-positioned at the first sight. 
`I am new here, and don't have enough reputations to post images yet`
[1.first sight](https://i-am-k.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/pic1.png)
[2.lamps?](https://i-am-k.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/pic2.png)

However, if I carefully move my viewpoint(camera?) into the house, and some of the inside structures start to show. After wondering around the entire inside space of the house, and pulling back my viewpoint to the outside world, the rendered scene seems perfect.
[3.lamps!](https://i-am-k.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/pic3.png)
[4.correct scene](https://i-am-k.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/pic4.png)

(The calculation and assembling process for the 3d model should be correct.)

Questions:

1. Is there any important step I'm missing?
2. Are there possible workarounds to ensure the scene is rendered correctly?
3. May I and should I try to "walk" the camera around programmatically to achieve the correctly rendered scene?

Hope that I've described my problem clear enough.
Any suggestion is helpful!

```
Model3DCollection collection； //pre-assembled data
ObservableElement3DCollection obCollection = new ObservableElement3DCollection();
foreach (var m3d in collection)
{
    if (m3d is GeometryModel3D gm3D)
    {
        MeshGeometry3D meshGeometry3D = gm3D.Geometry as MeshGeometry3D;
        HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.MeshGeometry3D meshGeometry = CastGeometry(meshGeometry3D);
        var model = new MeshGeometryModel3D()
        {
            Material = CastMaterial(gm3D.Material),
            Transform = m3d.Transform,
            Geometry = meshGeometry,
            CullMode = CullMode.Front
        };
        meshGeometry.UpdateOctree();
        obCollection.Add(model);
    }
}
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(obCollection));
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using separate thread instead of UI thread to load your models?

Seems like the transforms are not getting updated.

Make sure following is running in UI thread:

```
        var model = new MeshGeometryModel3D()
        {
            Material = CastMaterial(gm3D.Material),
            Transform = m3d.Transform,
            Geometry = meshGeometry,
            CullMode = CullMode.Front
        };
        obCollection.Add(model);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I reviewed my code. I did use `SynchronizationContext.Post` instead of `Send`, which might be a bit async. However, after testing with `Send`, the outcome didn't get any better. Currently, I am trying to use the **WPF** version of HelixToolkit instead of the **WPF.SharpDX** version. So far, only a few errors of face normal mis-calculation poped up, the overall scene seems fine. But I am concerned about the performance issue when the model gets much bigger. I was told the SharpDX version offers better performance, so it would be the best if the problem can be solved.

Comment: Would be helpful if you can create a sample project to show this problem. You can also try to run the file load demo in helixtoolkit Sharpdx example and see if your model can be loaded correctly.

Comment: After checking most of the `Viewport3DX` rendering switches, I found one particular switch called `EnableDeferredRendering` which was used to enable multithread rendering. However, this function caused deferred(delayed?) rendering effects, which (might) unfortunately created all those "to-be-rendered" giant blackish objects floating in the scene. So you were probably right about something not getting updated. By setting it to `False`, everything is fine now.

Comment: However, I believe my program will need the performance boost provided by the `EnableDeferredRendering` function, hence my following question: how may I determine whether the scene has finished rendering? Is there a related state I can monitor? Thanks!

Comment: How many models you need to render? Usually defer rendering only benefits when the scene has thousands of draw calls.